# Is there a Google Play Test channel that allows immediate testing, similar to Apples Internal Test

Tags: flutter, google-play

Have recently started using Flutter and so can deploy apps to Google Play as well as to Apples App Store. When I want to put an app out for internal test though I am finding some difficulties. With The App Store I can make internal tests for up to 25 users immediately (it doesn't have to be reviewed). However Google Play's Internal test channel still requires a review (which has taken 6 days recently). Is there any offering in Google Play that I can use deploy quicker to my Android users?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1):

Your first upload must be approved. After that they are automatic.

Comment: That’s not working at the moment. I rolled out a new release Monday and still waiting.

Comment: Sorry :( the internal test track has always been instant for me.